# Distinguish between read and connection timeouts in HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I want to distinguish between a **connection timeout** and a **read timeout** when using `HttpURLConnection`.
It throws `SocketTimeoutException` when any of the two happen.

In case a **connection timeout** happens, a message is included as the exception message. Example:

```
failed to connect to /192.168.X.X (port X) after Xms
```

In case a **read timeout** happens, no message is included.

Relevant:

- [setConnectTimeout](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#setConnectTimeout(int))
- [setReadTimeout](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#setReadTimeout(int))

Of course I could distinguish them by the fact that one seems to include a message and the other does not, but doesn't seem sensible. If the implementation changes the code breaks.

I would have expected two different exceptions. Perhaps there's something I'm missing.

Comment: Why the difference matters? It shoudn't.

Comment: It does for my use case. I want to take different actions.

Comment: What use case is that? It should be another solution...

Comment: It's probably too long to explain it in this SO question. If the difference did not matter, then I would like to ask you: Why are there two clearly different timeouts? As shown by the corresponding methods cited above.

Comment: I understand your concern. The fact is that Java exception hierarchy is flawed. Try to identify root cause for SQLException... That's why I'm suggesting you to give another solution a shot, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the timeout values are set using the setters, you can do the following

```
try {
  connection.connect();
  try {
    yourCustomReadMethodThatThrowsSocketTimeoutException(connection);
  } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
    Log.e("asdf", "this is a read timeout");
  }
} catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
  Log.e("asdf", "this is a connect timeout");
}
```